# Why calling printf here goes to infinite printing the messages?

Tags: c, linux, file-read

The goal is block the thread until new data is written to the file. I'm using `read()` to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sigint_handler(int sig) {
    printf("received SINT, exiting gracefully, com mto carinho...\n");
    exit(0);
}

int main() {

    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);

    char buffer[256] = { 0 };
    int fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY);
    
    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("error opening file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1) {
        
        ssize_t nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if(nbytes == -1) {
            printf("error reading file\n");
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        }
        
        //printf("new data: ");
        printf("%.*s", (int) nbytes, buffer);

    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I do call `printf("new data: )` it goes print "new data: " infinitely but if I omit that and leave only `printf("%.*s", (int) nbytes, buffer);` it print the contents read from read() then block the current thread... what is causing that and how do I fix this?

Comment: What if `nbytes` is zero (EOF)? How do you expect the loop to terminate in a non-error case?

Comment: Add `if (nbytes == 0) {` `break;` `}`.

Comment: @IanAbbott He doesn't want to break -- he's trying to implement `tail -f`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's supposed to terminate with Ctrl+C. That application is supposed to keep reading new changes added to a file by other application that runs indefinidely

Comment: Reading from a regular file never blocks. When you're at the end of the file, `read()` returns `0`.

Comment: @Coder Then don't print at least in case there is no new data.

Comment: And to keep from getting into a tight loop, sleep briefly when it returns 0.

Comment: Instead of implementing this yourself, you can use `popen("tail -f filename")`

Comment: Aside: Both printf(3) and exit(0) are async-signal-unsafe. The behaviour of signal(3) is unportable. Use sigaction(2) instead.

Comment: So something like `if (nbytes == 0) {` `sleep(1);` `continue;` `}` could be used. Real `tail` programs are a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: @Barmar How can I block reading a regular file?

Comment: You can't. As I said above, reading from a regular file *never blocks*.

Comment: @Barmar didn't know about `tail -f` I'll certainly use that instead of

Comment: @Haris so use `exit(0)` from `sigaction(2)` is totally fine?

Comment: No, the function is async-signal-unsafe. It can't be called in a signal handler. It's undefined behaviour. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: @Haris How can I exit the application gracefully when ctrl+c is pressed?

Comment: kill(2) or raise(3). It won't be very graceful, albeit.

Comment: can i kill from sigaction? is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

My apologies for making this a less-than-perfect answer.  But since nobody has answered this already, I figured a quick pointing in the right direction might already be helpful.

What you want to do is to look at the `select()` or `poll()` system calls, the latter one is probably easiest to use.

These are intended to monitor a set of file descriptors and block the calling thread until some state on them changed.  You can configure which kinds of state changes you are interested in.

The `read()` system call, on the other hand, is not guaranteed te reliably block etc., when there is no data available.

So your program should be calling either `select` (which needs some messing around with signal masks) or `poll` in a loop.

You can configure it so that your thread will be woken up on both input as well as error conditions.  Then you can distinguish the two and when more data is available, do a non-blocking `read`.

I'm sorry, but I'm too tired at the moment to provide some actual code samples, but hope this will point you in the right direction.

---

So I have just tried that with both `select` and `poll` and unfortunately, that only works when monitoring a socket, a pipe or something like standard input, but not a regular file.

Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <poll.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY);

    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("error opening file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Comment this out to use your file instead of stdin.
    fd = STDIN_FILENO;

    while(1) {
        struct pollfd fds[1];
        char buffer[BUFSIZ];
        ssize_t nbytes;
        int ret;

        struct timeval timeout;
        fd_set readfds;
        int nready;

        timeout.tv_sec = 60;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(fd, &readfds);

        printf("loop\n");

        nready = select(fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        if (nready == -1) {
            printf("select() failed.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (nready == 0) {
            printf("time out.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readfds)) {
            printf("data available.\n");
        } else {
            printf("select() didn't report data available.\n");
        }

        fds[0].fd = fd;
        fds[0].events = POLLIN;
        fds[0].revents = 0;

        ret = poll(fds, 1, INFTIM);

        printf("poll() returned %d - %x\n", ret, fds[0].revents);
        if (ret != 1) {
            printf("poll failed with exit code %d, revents %x\n", ret, fds[0].revents);
            break;
        }

        if (fds[0].revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP)) {
            printf("file has been closed.\n");
            break;
        }

        if ((fds[0].revents & (POLLIN | POLLRDNORM)) == 0) {
            printf("poll somehow didn't return POLLRDNORM.\n");
            break;
        }

        nbytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if(nbytes == -1) {
            printf("error reading file\n");
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        }

        printf("new data: ");
        printf("%.*s\n", (int) nbytes, buffer);

        sleep(5);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I believe what is happening here is that because it is a regular file and not a socket or a pipe, the `EOF` condition is always directly readable - and therefore both `select()` and `poll()` will return immediately, signalling "input" (the end of the file) being available.

You might want to look into something like this: https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch

Or, if you are on Linux, use `inotify` directly: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html